# hi want to show the names from other classes to the Basic class

Tags: django, django-models

but when i run it i shows errors that it cant find the muscel_id  i Muscel class, how can i show only the names. i ma trying to build a workout plan using django

```
class Days(models.Model):
    day_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Muscel(models.Model):
    Muscel_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)


class Basic(models.Model):
    dagen_basic = models.ForeignKey(Days, related_name='days_basic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    muskel = models.ForeignKey(Muscel.Muscel_name, related_name='muskel_basic', 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercise_name = models.ForeignKey(Exercise.exercise_name, related_name='exercise_name_basic', 
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sets = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
class Muscel(models.Model):
    muscel_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.muscel_name
```

add **str** on your Muscel model,

```
class Basic(models.Model):
    ......
    muskel = models.ForeignKey(Muscel, related_name='muskel_basic', 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercise_name = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name='exercise_name_basic', 
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ......
```

remove .Muscel_name on ForeignKey